# GCP Data Fusion : Custom Plugin Testing: Could not find artifact jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.6

Tags: java, plugins, dependencies, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I am trying to develop my own plugin for GCP Data Fusion. So I followed the documentation, and cloned the example from https://github.com/data-integrations/example-transform.

But when building the project, I get a problem with the import of dependencies needed for testing :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cdap.cdap</groupId>
        <artifactId>hydrator-test</artifactId>
        <version>${cdap.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I get the following error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project plugins: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.example:plugins:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.6 at specified path /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]
```

[image]

What can I do to solve this problem and test my plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDAP should run in Java version 8. So once you download JDK, set the Java home like

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/buildtools/java/jdk8/
```

and then try running your Maven command again.

Answer (score 0):

VFS-606 - tools.jar not available in Java 9
This exclusion can be removed after upgrading Hadoop
to 2.7.1 or later
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VFS-606